Wrong result from xargs du | tail
I'm trying to calculate the size of an rsync backup before executing it:
du -hs -- $(rsync -avn --exclude --delete $source $target | grep / | grep -v " bytes/sec" | grep -v "deleting " | cut -d "/" -f2- |  awk 'NF' | awk '$0="$source/"$0')

It fails with error: Argument list too long.
As far as I understand the command is bigger then the ARG_MAX limit.
I also tried xargs, but it fails too:
rsync -avn --exclude --delete $source $target | grep / | grep -v " bytes/sec" | grep -v "deleting " | cut -d "/" -f2- | awk 'NF' | awk '$0="$source/"$0'| xargs -P4 -n9999999  du  -hs -- 2>/dev/null | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'}
(It ends with output 23GB but it is far more.)
My question is: Is there another way to pre-calculate the size of an rsync backup?
Edit:
I've got a lot of files in my home-dir.
..
/home/$USER/foo/
/home/$USER/foo/bar
/home/$USER/test/
/home/$USER/test/test
/home/$USER/blah/
...

rsync puts me out the dirs but in the wrong format so du is not able to find them
du -hs -- | $(rsync -avn --delete $HOME /tmp)
bash: sending: Command not found.

The goal I want to archive is that du is able to find the files by pathnames without rsync-info, so I just grep the filenames and attach /home/$USER as prefix (look above) with this error:
bash: /usr/bin/du: Argument list too long

or with xargs
xargs du -hs -- $(rsync -avn --delete $HOME /tmp | grep / | grep -v " bytes/sec" | grep -v "deleting " | cut -d "/" -f2- |  awk 'NF' | awk '$0="/home/MyUser/"$0' )

bash: /usr/bin/xargs: Argument list too long

If I try a subfolder, containig fewer files, it works and du gives me the filesizes of the data.
Trying the same with xargs it gives me - nothing (blinking cursor- no output).
xargs du -hs -- $(rsync -avn $HOME/foo /tmp | grep / | grep -v " bytes/sec" | grep -v "deleting " | cut -d "/" -f2- |  awk 'NF' | awk '$0="/home/MyUser/foo/"$0' )


Your first attempt make me think the files in source are in your machine. In that case, you could get directory size without rsync : du -hs "$source"

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

The reason xargs "fails" is that you discard some of its output.
To recap, when you get "argument list too long", that means the string containing your arguments was bigger than the kernel constant ARG_MAX; see e.g. Bash command line and input limit
xargs works around this by running the same command multiple times. So for example, if echo one two three four was too long, and you split it with xargs, you'd effectively run
echo one two
echo three four

You'll notice that whereas the original output would have been a single line, this reformulation produces two lines. You need to be cognizant of things like this when using xargs.
Returning to your example, you'll need to accept that du will possibly be run multiple times, and take additional steps to collect the separate results back together. You were already using Awk; so just write a better Awk script.
rsync -avn --exclude --delete "$source" "$target" |
awk -v s="$source" '
  /bytes\/sec|deleting/ { next }
  /\// { sub(/^[^/]*\//, s "/", $0);
    print } ' |
xargs -P4 du -ks -- 2>/dev/null |
awk '{ sum += $1 }
  END { print sum / 1024*1024*1024 }'

Notice also that we don't want to use du -h because then we can't predict what output units it will use. xargs could end up running it on a single tiny file in the last invocation, and then you'd get output in bytes or kilobytes or megabytes instead of gigabytes with du -h. We instead calculate the total in Awk, and then format it in gigabytes.
(You could get fancy and not hardcode gigabytes, but I'll leave that as an exercise. Perhaps see also File size in human readable format)
I also refactored your complex grep | cut / | awk into just one Awk script, though without access to the data, it's hard to be sure that it's correct. I believe I fixed a bug where presumably you wanted to add the value of the shell variable source in the output, not the static text $source. Remember, the shell and Awk are two different languages, and don't have access to each other's variables. I'll also point to useless use of grep which has a rationale for some of this refactoring.
Finally, quote your variables and don't hardcode a large -n value in xargs when you obviously can't know how many arguments you can squeeze in; it will default to the largest possible number anyway.

Thanks for your input but it didn't work.. maybe it is because of me missunderstanding something, but it ends at number which is totally different from everything logically.
I am not sure if I understand you right but the -n should be same as --dry-run:
--dry-run, -n            perform a trial run with no changes made

Can you edit your question to include sample output from a small run on rsync which doesn't work correctly and the du output for the file entries? I suppose du could end up printing the same path multiple times so you'd need to throw in sort -u

Didn't notice the -n there; sorry about that.

What du you mean with "small"? Arguments, output-lenght, pure rsync (which is working btw)?

Oh, you mean the du-output? That works flawlessly, I wanted add the source-path from $source to the rsync-outpu so du can find it within the fs. du gave some errors because of spaces in filenames but overall it was able to find most of the data.

The guidance for providing an [mre] is worth a read. We can't test without files which resemble the ones you are having trouble with. For instance, can you synthesize an example with just 3-5 small input files which produces the wrong output? (You probably need to force it with xargs -n 2 or even -n 1 to reproduce the symptom if it's caused by repetitions in the du output.)

I was finally able to solve the problem by using rsync's --stats option and grabbing the "Total transferred file size":
rsync -avn --stats --delete $source $1 | grep "Total transferred file size:" | awk {'print $5'} | tr -d '.'
It returns the difference in byte without any error.

You still want to avoid the useless grep and the tr is easy to kill off at the same time; awk '/Total transferred file size:/ { s = $5; sub(/[.]/, "", s); print s }'

Also, again, you want to quote "$source" and "$1". You test with really simple paths and then get really weird errors when your script needs to handle file names with spaces and tabs and single quotes and what have you in production. Quoting easily saves you from that.
